# Failover on voyage os using eth0 and ppp0 interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

Hi I am having problem for failover handling on voyage os.
I have a system with eth0 and ppp0 interfaces where eth0 is primary and ppp0 is a secondary path for traffic.

```
root@voyage:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.40.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     10     0        0 ppp0

10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0

10.255.255.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

192.168.40.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

When I unplug or ifdown eth0 default route entry for eth0 is deleted and traffic flows through ppp0 interface because it's metric is higher than eth0.
When I plugged in eth0 default route entry for eth0 is created and traffic flows through eth0 interface. But when LAN is down as eth0 is on LAN, default route is not deleted so failover is not take place. Please any one tell me is there any way to do that  When LAN is down default route automatically deleted from routing table after some time period.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but could save some others persons time...
You could use a script that you copy into */etc/network/if-down.d/*, make it executable, so as to delete your default route (route add default ...).
To make it runs you need to add a : 
     post-up /etc/network/if-down.d/ 
in */etc/network/interface* in the eth0 part.

Hope it will help...